# Getting an undefined error when trying to pull the URL from my css using JS

Tags: javascript

I thought I got this one right, apparently not as I'm getting an "undefined" error

Here is my CSS

```
<main id="tm-content" class="tm-content">
<ul class="uk-breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="/countries">Countries</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/countries/united-states">United States</a>
</li>
```

Will this bit of javascript define `https://www.example.com/countries` ?

```
    function getHref() {
  return $('.uk-breadcrumb li a')[0].href
}
```

[image]

Any suggestions or guidance would be very much appreciated

Comment: Which library are you using for the `$`? jQuery?

Comment: Try `$('.uk-breadcrumb li a').first().attr("href")`. You are mixing vanilla JS and jQuery syntaxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not have the `$` defined.

For this simple case, you should be able to use `document.querySelectorAll` in its place:

```js
function getHref() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.uk-breadcrumb li a')[0].href;
}

alert(getHref());
```

```html
<ul class="uk-breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="/countries">Countries</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/countries/united-states">United States</a>
</li>
```

Note that this [doesn't have full support below IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#browser_compatibility), if you need that then i'd recommend jQuery.